# AutoMapper - Get error: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping while mapping record type

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, automapper, record

I searched a lot but no solution resolved my problem. Actually, I want to  use AutoMapper to map two `record` type with the same arguments but I get the following error:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types:
> TadaLegalEmployerDto -> TadaLegalEmployerModel
> EmployeeAndEmployer.Api.Models.TadaDtos.TadaLegalEmployerDto -> EmployeeAndEmployer.Api.Application.Queries.GetTadaLegalEmployer.TadaLegalEmployerModel
>
> Destination Member:
> LegalEmployer

Source:

```cs
public record TadaGetLegalEmployerResponseDto(string data,
    TadaLegalEmployerDto LegalEmployer, string Starter);

public record TadaLegalEmployerDto(string SNationalId,
    string SRegistrationNumber, TadaCentralOfficeDto CentralOffice);

public record TadaCentralOfficeDto(string Province);
```

Destination:

```cs
public record TadaGetLegalEmployerResponseModel(string data,
    TadaLegalEmployerModel LegalEmployer,string Starter);

public record TadaLegalEmployerModel(string SNationalId,
    string SRegistrationNumber, TadaCentralOfficeModel CentralOffice);

public record TadaCentralOfficeModel(string Province);
```

Mapping Class:

```cs
public class GetLegalEmployerResponseDtoToGetLegalEmployerResponseModel : Profile
{
    public GetLegalEmployerResponseDtoToGetLegalEmployerResponseModel()
    {
        CreateMap<TadaGetLegalEmployerResponseDto, TadaGetLegalEmployerResponseModel>();
    }
}
```

and in my handler, I have:

```cs
var dto = await _myService.GetLegalEmployersAsync();
var resultModel = _mapper.Map<TadaGetLegalEmployerResponseModel>(dto);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception message is quite clear. You need the mapping rule to map from `TadaLegalEmployerDto` to `TadaLegalEmployerModel`.

```cs
public GetLegalEmployerResponseDtoToGetLegalEmployerResponseModel()
{
    CreateMap<TadaGetLegalEmployerResponseDto, TadaGetLegalEmployerResponseModel>();

    CreateMap<TadaLegalEmployerDto, TadaLegalEmployerModel>();

    CreateMap<TadaCentralOfficeDto, TadaCentralOfficeModel>();
}
```